# I can create firebase user using this code, but how can I add display Name, phone Number and other information in default firebase user table? Thanks

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is my funcation code.

```
const signUpFun = () => {
    if (isValidForm()) {

        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                // Signed in 
                const user = userCredential.user;
                setbitdata({});
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                const errorCode = error.code;
                const errorMessage = error.message;
                setEmailAndPasswordCheck(true)
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setEmailAndPasswordCheck(false)
                }, 3500)
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { getAuth, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
const auth = getAuth();
updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
  displayName: "My Name", photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
}).then(() => {
  // Profile updated!
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error occurred
});
```

If you are using firebase version 8, then you should use like these:

```
import firebase from "firebase";

const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.updateProfile({
  displayName: "My Name",
  photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
}).then(() => {
  // Update successful
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error occurred
});
```

Firebase have very great documentation, you should probably [read](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile) that, as like @Alexandros Giotas mentioned the link for official Documentation for your question

Comment: I can only update the DisplayName And photoURL the phone number can't be updated with this function

Comment: You need to use `User.updatePhoneNumber()` to update phone number. (doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#updatephonenumber)
`User.updateProfile()` can only update `displayName` and `photoUrl`. (doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#updateprofile)

Answer (score -1):

You're probably looking for the `updateProfile` method.
Using modular imports:

```
import { getAuth, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
const auth = getAuth();
updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
  displayName: "Your display name here",
  // more updating..
}).then(() => {
  // Success
}).catch((e) => {
  // Handle errors.
});
```

Remember that `updateProfile` returns a Promise which you should handle, with either `then() & catch()` as shown above or `await` if you're updating within an `async` function.

I encourage you to read the [Firebase docs on updating a user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile).
There are more code snippets there, that answer your question probably better than I did.